# Discord.py error: "ValueError: <class 'str'> is not a valid ChannelType"

Tags: discord.py

I don't understand what the error is.

```
> Ignoring exception in command weather:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timoha/discord_bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/enums.py", line 168, in __call__
   
>  return cls._enum_value_map_[value]
> KeyError: <class 'str'>

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timoha/discord_bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 124, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(arg)
  File "/home/timoha/discord_bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 980, in _invoke
    await self.callback(ctx, **kwargs)
  File "/home/timoha/discord_bot/main.py", line 166, in weather
    async with discord.channel.ChannelType(value=str):
  File "/home/timoha/discord_bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/enums.py", line 170, in __call__

> raise ValueError(f"{value!r} is not a valid {cls.__name__}")
> ValueError: <class 'str'> is not a valid ChannelType
> 
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timoha/discord_bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/bot.py", line 1114, in invoke_application_command
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/timoha/discord_bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 375, in invoke
    await injected(ctx)
  File "/home/timoha/discord_bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 132, in wrapped

> raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
> discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: ValueError: <class 'str'> is not a valid ChannelType
```

Code:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="weather", description="Погода")
async def weather(ctx, *, city: str): 
    city_name = city
    complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name
    response = requests.get(complete_url)
    x = response.json()
    channel = ctx.message
    if x["cod"] != "404":
        async with discord.channel.ChannelType(value=str):
            value=str
            y = x["главный"]
            current_temperature = y["температура"]
            current_temperature_celsiuis =str(round(current_temperature - 273.15))
            current_pressure = y["давление"]
            current_humidity = y["влажность"]
            z = x["погода"]
            weather_description = z[0]["описание"]
            weather_description = z[0]["описание"]
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Погода в {city_name}",
                              color=ctx.guild.me.top_role.color,
                              timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,)
            embed.add_field(name="Описание", value=f"**{weather_description}**", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Температура(C)", value=f"**{current_temperature_celsiuis}°C**", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Влажность(%)", value=f"**{current_humidity}%**", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Atmospheric Pressure(hPa)", value=f"**{current_pressure}hPa**", inline=False)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.ibb.co/CMrsxdX/weather.png")
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Запрошенный {ctx.author.name}")
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await channel.send("Город не найден.")
```

I tried to change a lot of things, but I still can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code - that error is probably just the first one. I've attempted to rewrite what you've provided with some explanation but hopefully it replicates what you're trying to do.

```py
@bot.slash_command(name="weather", description="Погода")
async def weather(ctx, *, city: str):

    # as we're doing an API call here - let's defer so the interaction doesn't timeout
    await ctx.defer()

    # no reason to redefine another variable called 'city_name' equal to 'city' - just use 'city' everywhere

    # could also use a f-string for creating the URL here
    # complete_url = f"{base_url}appid={api_key}&q={city}"
    complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city
    response = requests.get(complete_url)
    json_response = response.json()

    if json_response["cod"] == "404":
        # if it's 404, let's send the error message and return early
        # means we don't have a big nested "if" block
        await channel.send("Город не найден.")
        return

    y = json_response["главный"]
    z = json_response["погода"]

    current_temperature = y["температура"]
    current_temperature_celsiuis =str(round(current_temperature - 273.15))
    current_pressure = y["давление"]
    current_humidity = y["влажность"]
    
    weather_description = z[0]["описание"]
    weather_description = z[0]["описание"]
            
    # create the embed
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f"Погода в {city}",
        color=ctx.guild.me.top_role.color,
        timestamp=ctx.message.created_at
    )
    embed.add_field(name="Описание", value=f"**{weather_description}**", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Температура(C)", value=f"**{current_temperature_celsiuis}°C**", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Влажность(%)", value=f"**{current_humidity}%**", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Atmospheric Pressure(hPa)", value=f"**{current_pressure}hPa**", inline=False)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.ibb.co/CMrsxdX/weather.png")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Запрошенный {ctx.author.name}")
    
    # now let's send our response
    # ctx.send will send to the channel that the user used the slash command in
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The [`ctx`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) variable docs.

What I changed:

- removed creating a variable called `city_name` that was exactly equal to `city` - seemed redundant
- added [`ctx.defer()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.defer) - if our code takes a little while it's good to defer so the interaction doesn't timeout
- removed `channel = ctx.message`. We can get the channel later *if* we need to (we don't in this case) but this was setting it equal to the message that invoked the application command (which isn't *really* a message) so we aren't accomplishing anything here anyways
- if we get a `404` response; send error message and return. Better to do this than have a big nested if block in my opinion.
- I also renamed `x` to `json_response` as I prefer descriptive variable names but I gave up on `y` and `z`.
- got rid of the whatever the `async with` statement was trying to accomplish
- used [`ctx.send(embed=embed)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send) at the bottom to send your created embed to the channel that the user used the application command in

*Hopefully*, this is what you want it to do and hopefully you understand what's going on a bit now. It might be worth having a look through some of the examples and documentation to get a better grasp on how it all works.

Another change you *could* make, is swapping out `requests` for [`aiohttp-requests`](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp-requests/) to make non-blocking API calls.

Comment: read my answer)

Comment: Well, that's a `KeyError`. That means the key you're looking for (whatever `главный` is) in the JSON response from the API isn't there.

Comment: Can you please tell you more, I see because of the crooked translator I don't understand you a little

Comment: Well, `json_response` is the JSON representation of the data returned from the web API you're querying for weather data. That is, it's a dictionary of {"key": "value"}. The error is complaining that the key you're looking for, `главный`, isn't in the dictionary. You can try adding a `print(json_response)` before to see what's in it.

Comment: I'm sorry, of course, but I understood about JSON, but here's what procedure to do to make everything work. I need to create a response file.json or just insert your key somewhere

Comment: It's _your_ key - I copied that from the code _you_ provided. I have no idea what the API returns - change the keys as you need. It's from your line `y = x["главный"]`.